# Adding array values via for loop

Tags: javascript

I want to rewrite this line:

```
var mySum = myArray[0] + myArray[1] + myArray[2] + myArray[3];
```

Considering that I do not know a number of elements in the array, I am thinking of this:

```
 for (var = count; count < array.length; count++)
    {
    var mySum = ?? // but what's the math for this
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather easy!

In your language it would look like

```
var mySum = 0;
for (var count = 0; count < array.length; count++) {
     mySum += array[count];
    // mySum = mySum + array[count]
    // note that I declared mySum outside the loop
}
```

In something like java it would look like this

```
int[] array = new int[100];
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    count += array[i];
    // i is the loop iterator
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems like this:

```
var mySum = 0;
for( var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++ ) mySum += myArray[ i ];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var mySum = 0;
for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) mySum += myArray[i];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var mySum = 0;
var myArray = [1,2,3,5,8,13]

for(var i = 0,amount = myArray.length;i < amount;i++) {
    mySum = mySum + myArray[i]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function instead to implement it as single-line Javascript code.

```
var sum = myArray.reduce(function(acc, c){return acc + c;}, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var = count; count < array.length; count++)
    {
    var mySum +=myArray[count];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var mySum = 0; 
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     var mySum  += array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var mySum = 0; 
for (var = count; count < myArray.length; count++)
{
    mySum +=myArray[count];
}
```